# Prediction of enantiomeric excess through kinetics

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, chirality

[image: Reaction Sequence]

Suppose we have a reaction such as the one represented above. Is there a method to estimate enantiomeric excess of the product if the rate constants are known and the product does not isomerize (and the other stereocenter doesn't either)?

To simplify, let us suppose that $a=100$, $b=900$, $c=50$, $d=30$.

We will begin with a racemic mixture (of the first two compounds). Methods that I've tried so far seem inadequate to approximate enantiomeric excess.

Comment: Did you try chiral GC? Guessing from cyclopropyl amine (b.p.: ~$\pu{50^\circ C}$), these compounds shhould be fairly low boiling. Alternatively, if you suspect they'd recemize faster at higher temperature,  try chiral HPLC.

Comment: This is a computational study (with a different compound, I am just using cyclopropylamine as a model), I was wondering if there is a way to predict enantiomeric excess with rate constants.

Comment: Just model it numerically. A simple python script can give you the answer within minutes. Btw. what do you mean by racemic mixture of the first two compounds? You can just look at the series of one enantiomer in each case just like drawn.

Comment: Modeling using python worked well, thank you.